# drawImage is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java, methods, int, double, getter

Look I'm going to be up front about this. My assignment is due soon and i've spent way too many hours trying to fix this problem with no success at all. I'm essentially clueless at what the issue is and I really dont know where to look. I have 5 classes, I will try and post them all to ensure I get the answer, I am unable to change GameManager or Goal but I am allowed to change any other class.

The problem lines are this.canvasGraphics.drawImage(player.getCurrentImage() where drawImage says it isnt applicable for the arguments

and 
this.enemies[i].getX() - (this.enemies[i].getCurrentImage().getWidth() / 2),
this.enemies[i].getY() - (this.enemies[i].getCurrentImage().getHeight() / 2), null);
where getWidth and getHeight show an almost identical error

thanks in advance

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class GameManager extends JFrame implements KeyListener {
private int canvasWidth;
private int canvasHeight;
private int borderLeft;
private int borderTop;
private BufferedImage canvas;
private Stage stage;
private Enemy[] enemies;
private Player player;
private Goal goal;
private Graphics gameGraphics;
private Graphics canvasGraphics;
private int numEnemies;
private boolean continueGame;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // During development, you can adjust the values provided in the brackets below
    // as needed. However, your code must work with different/valid combinations
    // of values.
    int choice;
    do{
        GameManager managerObj = new GameManager(1920, 1080);
        choice=JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Play again?", "", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
    }while(choice==JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
  System.exit(0);
}

public GameManager(int preferredWidth, int preferredHeight) {
    int maxEnemies; 
    try{
        maxEnemies=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many enemies? (Default is 5)"));
        if (maxEnemies<0)
            maxEnemies=5;
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        maxEnemies=5;
    }

    this.borderLeft = getInsets().left;
    this.borderTop = getInsets().top;
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    if (screenSize.width < preferredWidth)
        this.canvasWidth = screenSize.width - getInsets().left - getInsets().right;
    else
        this.canvasWidth = preferredWidth - getInsets().left - getInsets().right;
    if (screenSize.height < preferredHeight)
        this.canvasHeight = screenSize.height - getInsets().top - getInsets().bottom;
    else
        this.canvasHeight = preferredHeight - getInsets().top - getInsets().bottom;
    setSize(this.canvasWidth, this.canvasHeight);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    addKeyListener(this);
    Random rng = new Random();
    this.canvas = new BufferedImage(this.canvasWidth, this.canvasHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    // Create a Stage object to hold the background images
    this.stage = new Stage();
    // Create a Goal object with its initial x and y coordinates
    this.goal = new Goal((Math.abs(rng.nextInt()) % (this.canvasWidth)),
            (Math.abs(rng.nextInt()) % this.canvasHeight));
    // Create a Player object with its initial x and y coordinates
    this.player = new Player((Math.abs(rng.nextInt()) % (this.canvasWidth)),
            (Math.abs(rng.nextInt()) % this.canvasHeight));
    // Create the Enemy objects, each with a reference to this (GameManager) object
    // and their initial x and y coordinates.
    this.numEnemies = maxEnemies;
    this.enemies = new Enemy[this.numEnemies];
    for (int i = 0; i < this.numEnemies; i++) {
        this.enemies[i] = new Enemy(this, Math.abs(rng.nextInt()) % (this.canvasWidth),
                Math.abs(rng.nextInt()) % this.canvasHeight);
    }
    this.gameGraphics = getGraphics();
    this.canvasGraphics = this.canvas.getGraphics();
    this.continueGame = true;
    long gameStartTime=System.nanoTime();

    while (this.continueGame) {
        updateCanvas();
    }
    this.stage.setGameOverBackground();
    double gameTime=(System.nanoTime()-gameStartTime)/1000000000.0;
    updateCanvas();
    this.gameGraphics.setFont(new Font(this.gameGraphics.getFont().getFontName(), Font.PLAIN, 50)); 
    if (gameTime<1)
        this.gameGraphics.drawString("Oops! Better luck next time...",  this.canvasWidth/3, this.canvasHeight/2 - 50);
    else
        this.gameGraphics.drawString("You survived " + String.format("%.1f", gameTime)+ " seconds with "+this.numEnemies+" enemies!",
            this.canvasWidth/4, this.canvasHeight/2 - 50);
  return;
}

public void updateCanvas() {
    long start = System.nanoTime();

    this.goal.performAction();
    // If the player is alive, this should move the player in the direction of the
    // key that has been pressed
    // Note: See keyPressed and keyReleased methods in the GameManager class.
    this.player.performAction();
    // If the enemy is alive, the enemy must move towards the Player. The Player object
    // is obtained via the GameManager object that is given at the time of creating an Enemy
    // object.
    // Note: The amount that the enemy moves by must be much smaller than that of
    // the player above or else the game becomes too hard to play.
    for (int i = 0; i < this.numEnemies; i++) {
        this.enemies[i].performAction();
    }
    if ((Math.abs(this.goal.getX() - this.player.getX()) < (this.goal.getCurrentImage().getWidth() / 2))
            && (Math.abs(this.goal.getY() - this.player.getY()) < (this.goal.getCurrentImage().getWidth() / 2))) {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.numEnemies; i++) {
            // Sets the image of the enemy to the "dead" image and sets its status to
            // indicate dead
            this.enemies[i].die();
        }
        // Sets the background of the stage to the finished game background.
        this.stage.setGameOverBackground();
        this.continueGame = false;
    }
    // If an enemy is close to the player or the goal, the player and goal die
    int j = 0;
    while (j < this.numEnemies) {
        if ((Math.abs(this.player.getX() - this.enemies[j].getX()) < (this.player.getCurrentImage().getWidth() / 2))
                && (Math.abs(this.player.getY() - this.enemies[j].getY()) < (this.player.getCurrentImage().getWidth()
                        / 2))) {
            this.player.die();
            this.goal.die();
            this.stage.setGameOverBackground();
            j = this.numEnemies;
            this.continueGame = false;
        }
        else if ((Math.abs(this.goal.getX() - this.enemies[j].getX()) < (this.goal.getCurrentImage().getWidth() / 2))
                && (Math.abs(this.goal.getY() - this.enemies[j].getY()) < (this.goal.getCurrentImage().getWidth()
                        / 2))) {
            this.player.die();
            this.goal.die();
            this.stage.setGameOverBackground();
            j = this.numEnemies;
            this.continueGame = false;
        }
        j++;
    }
    try {
        // Draw stage
        this.canvasGraphics.drawImage(stage.getCurrentImage(), 0, 0, null);
        // Draw goal
        this.canvasGraphics.drawImage(this.goal.getCurrentImage(),
                this.goal.getX() - (this.goal.getCurrentImage().getWidth() / 2),
                this.goal.getY() - (this.goal.getCurrentImage().getHeight() / 2), null);
        // Draw player
        this.canvasGraphics.drawImage(player.getCurrentImage(),
                this.player.getX() - (this.player.getCurrentImage().getWidth() / 2),
                this.player.getY() - (this.player.getCurrentImage().getHeight() / 2), null);
        // Draw enemies
        for (int i = 0; i < this.numEnemies; i++) {
            this.canvasGraphics.drawImage(this.enemies[i].getCurrentImage(),
                    this.enemies[i].getX() - (this.enemies[i].getCurrentImage().getWidth() / 2),
                    this.enemies[i].getY() - (this.enemies[i].getCurrentImage().getHeight() / 2), null);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    // Draw everything.
    this.gameGraphics.drawImage(this.canvas, this.borderLeft, this.borderTop, this);
    long end = System.nanoTime();
    this.gameGraphics.setFont(new Font(this.gameGraphics.getFont().getFontName(), Font.PLAIN, 15)); 
    this.gameGraphics.drawString("FPS: " + String.format("%2d", (int) (1000000000.0 / (end - start))),
            this.borderLeft + 50, this.borderTop + 75);
  return;
}

public Player getPlayer() {
    return this.player;
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
    // Below, the setKey method is used to tell the Player object which key is
    // currently pressed. 

    // The Player object must keep track of the pressed key and use it for
    // determining the direction
    // to move.

    // Important: The setKey method in Player must not move the Player.
    if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
        this.player.setKey('L', true);
    if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        this.player.setKey('R', true);
    if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
        this.player.setKey('U', true);
    if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
        this.player.setKey('D', true);
    if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE)
        this.continueGame = false;
  return;
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
    // Below, the setKey method is used to tell the Player object which key is
    // currently released.

    // The Player object must keep track of the pressed key and use it for
    // determining the direction
    // to move.

    // Important: The setKey method in Player must not move the Player.
    if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
        this.player.setKey('L', false);
    if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        this.player.setKey('R', false);
    if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
        this.player.setKey('U', false);
    if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
        this.player.setKey('D', false);
  return;
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {
  return;
}
}
```

---

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.util.*;

public class Goal {
private int x;
private int y;
private BufferedImage imageCurrent;
private BufferedImage imageRunning;
private BufferedImage imageOver;

private int stepSize;
private Random rng; // Tip: Code that students write must not use randomness

public Goal(int x, int y) {
    try {
        this.imageRunning = ImageIO.read(new File("goal-alive.png"));
        this.imageOver = ImageIO.read(new File("goal-dead.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.stepSize = 10;

    this.rng = new Random(x + y); // Tip: Code that students write (elsewhere) must not use any randomness.

    this.imageCurrent = this.imageRunning;
    return;
}

public void performAction() {
    // The code below shows how the Goal can be moved by manipulating its x and y
    // coordinates.
    // Tip: Code that students write (elsewhere) must not use any randomness.
    this.x += this.rng.nextInt() % stepSize;
    this.y += this.rng.nextInt() % stepSize;
    return;
}

public int getY() {
    return this.y;
}

public int getX() {
    return this.x;
}

public BufferedImage getCurrentImage() {
    return this.imageCurrent;
}

public void die() {
    this.imageCurrent = this.imageOver;
    return;

}

}
```

---

```
import java.awt.Image;

public class Enemy {

private Image CurrentImage;
private int x;
private int y;

public Enemy(GameManager gameManager, int x, int y) {
}

public void performAction() {

}

public void die() {

}

public int getX() {
    return this.x;
}

public int getY() {
    return this.y;
}

public Image getCurrentImage() {
    return CurrentImage;
}

}
```

---

```
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class Player {

private Dimension CurrentImage;
private int x;
private int y;

public Player(int x1, int y1) {

}

public void performAction() {

}

public int getX() {
    return this.x;
}

public int getY() {
    return this.y;
}

public Dimension getCurrentImage() {
    return CurrentImage;
}

public void die() {

}

public void setKey(char c, boolean b) {

}

}
```

---

```
import java.awt.Image;

public class Stage {

public void setGameOverBackground() {

}

public Image getCurrentImage() {

    return null;
}

}
```

Comment: tl;dr. Please provide a SSCCE.

Answer (score 1):

`Player.getCurrentImage()` returns a `Dimension`, not an `Image`.

Comment: worked a treat thankyou, now I'm still having issues with getwidth and getheight, do you see the problem? it feels like its staring me in the face

Comment: @lucifer which gitwidth, getheight?

Comment: for both player and enemy, what do I add into those classes, I don't understand because goal has neither but seems to have no errors, I just don't understand, and I can't seem to find where the method is in any of this

Comment: `Enemy.getCurrentImage()` returns an `Image` whereas `Goal.getCurrentImage` returns a `BufferedImage`. `Image` doesn't have the methods `getWith()` and `getHeight()`. Try to use `BufferedImage`s everywhere.

Comment: I can't believe that worked, I barely understand what this all means but thankyou, so literally copying the goal files I was given to the enemy and adapting it was key, thanks a lot